# How to change where UnauthorizedAccessException redirects to in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

Pretty straightforward.
I'm throwing an UnauthorizedAccessException in an AuthorizationFilter.  I want UnauthorizedAccessException to head to an Error page, NOT to the /Account/Login page.
How can I make that change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple exception handlers

```
        try
        {
            // code here
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            Response.Redirect(errorPageUrl, false);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Response.Redirect(loginPageUrl, false);
        }
```

Comment: I can definitely tell it's Saturday by the fact that I didn't even think of doing the redirect on my own.  :-\

Answer (score 3):

Try setting up something like this in global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // excpt is the exception thrown
    // The exception that really happened is retrieved through the GetBaseException() method
    // because the exception returned by the GetLastError() is a HttpException
    Exception excpt = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();

      if(excpt is UnauthorizedAccessException)
      { 
        // redirect here
      }

}
```